# How to read from an Action that is needed on every page?

Tags: struts2

I'm new to Struts2.

How does one invoke methods from a class without using an ActionSupport-implemented-class? So a simple Java class.
It's because I want to add something to a include jsp file. Therefore this value is always valid - independent of the page one is requesting.

Probably simple.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why can't you just include the jsp file?

Comment: In addition, if you just want to call an arbitrary Java function *without* an associated rendering, you can do so via OGNL. You need to be clearer.

Comment: Revise your question to better explain what your actual need is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your Action without extending ActionSupport class.

`ActionSupport` is just for convenience 
`ActionSupport` has default implementations of common methods (e.g., `execute()`, `input()`), gives access to `Action.SUCCESS`, `Action.ERROR` and other result names, etc.

**Action Class:**

```
public class TestAction
{
    public String testMethod()
    {

      return "success";
    }
}
```

**Struts.xml:**

```
<action name="TestAction" class="com.TestAction" method="testMethod">
    <result name="success">Mypage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Can I not simply invoke the testMethod from a JSP page without the sturts.xml extension?

Comment: No, Mapping of the action is necessary in struts.xml

Answer (score 2):

Struts2 architecture does not require you to extend `ActionSupport` class. It is that flexible. `ActionSupport` is just a convenience and provides basic functionality like validation etc. You can write a simple pojo action class. All you need is to return a `String` that will be used to forward to a resource like `jsp`.

For Example

```
public class MyAction
{
    public String testAction()
    {
        //Perform your logic here. Note it is not mandatory to return SUCCESS here, you can actually return any String here, but make sure you map that String to a resource in your `struts.xml`
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```